# Different ways to compare a String

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing two strings with “==”: when will it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479334/comparing-two-strings-with-when-will-it-work)

I have the following code:

```
String s1 = new String("Test");
String s2 = new String("Test");

String s3 = "Test";
String s4 = "Test";

System.out.println(s1 == s2);
System.out.println(s3 == s4);
```

And I get the following output:

```
false
true
```

Why does the second comparison print `true`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Comparing two strings with “==”: when will it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7479334/844882)

Comment: it is the same issue, but the answer there is super confusing - does another, simpler answer here make sense?

Comment: @mfrankli I wouldn't call a very precise and in-depth answer confusing, at least not without qualification. It may be too advanced for a beginner, that I admit.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to compare a `String` is with,

```
 s1.equals(s2)
```

1. `System.out.println(s1==s2)` prints `false`, because `s1` and `s2` are pointing to different objects on the heap.
2. `System.out.println(s3==s4)` prints `true`, because `s3` and `s4` are object references which are pointing to the same object on the heap.

Comment: This is incorrect. `s3` and `s4` are **not** on the same heap as `s1` and `s2`. They both point to a `String` constant in the **String literal pool**.

Comment: i never said s3 and s4 are on the Heap, please read it again, I said that they are pointing on the same object on the heap......

Comment: Usually, "the heap" refers to the more general heap that is responsible for dynamic memory allocated using the `new` operator. In my answer, I would have mentioned either the String literal pool or String internalization, just to be as clear as possible :).

Comment: Now if your are taking abt heap, let me tell you that Heap has 2 areas, 1. Object Space 2. Memory Area .  Memory Area is the one where String pool resides, and various system classes, including the custom classes, and everything here is in byte form...

Comment: Yes, sorry... I shouldn't have said it was "incorrect". I still would have mentioned the String literal pool in my answer though. It still seems to me that you are getting the upvotes, so I doubt I did too much damage :P.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure it answers the question but :

`==` is used to compare the reference (the pointers)

so `s1==s2` don't check if the string are the same but if s1 and s2 are the same `String` instance.

To check equality you must use the `equals` function : `s1.equals(s2)`

As string are internalized, the behavior depends on the jvm and cannot be predicted (even if most implementations are the same)

Comment: It can be predicted if you know which JVM version you are using...

Comment: Of course, the last sentence miss an implicit "unless you know only one JVM implementation will be used"... best practice however would be not to rely on a specific implementation...

Comment: Hmm... are you about this? String interning can (and usually does) significantly improve efficiency and memory usage. I can't imagine a JVM that doesn't automatically intern strings...

Answer (score 2):

In Java, it is important to note, `==` always means "return true if these two things refer to the same instance of an object in memory"

When you declare a string using the constructor:

```
String s1 = new String("Foo");
String s2 = new String("Foo");
```

A ***new string instance*** is always created.  This means that even though they have the same value, `s1` and `s2` are never going to be the same object and as such `==` returns false.

There is a special case for constant strings however.  When you declare a string thus:

```
String s3 = "Foo";
String s4 = "Foo";
```

then a single constant string is created in the string pool, and both variables s3 and s4 point to it as a memory optimization.  This should be treated as an implementation detail however.  Comparison should still always be done using the Equals method.