# Value comparison is confusing me, not working properly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

[image: Screencap]

I am comparing two strings, and apparently they aren't equal but they are.  I was wondering what are some issues that could cause this, maybe datatype, hidden stuff that I can't see, or what.  Any input could be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: You're **not** doing value comparison; the `==` operator when applied to objects does *reference* comparison -  it will only return true if they're the exact same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String/Object comparison should use `equals()`, not `==` (excepts the case of String literal comparison)

Example:

```
if(string.equals(string2)){
}
```

`==` checks for reference equality, `equals()` checks for content equality. Read this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479334/comparing-two-strings-with-when-will-it-work?lq=1).

Comment: Just to add to this: == checks whether the references to the objects are equal, .equals() checks for character sequence equality

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Is this true for C++ too or Java specific?

Comment: @user1582340: Don't know about C++, but it is true in Java, not true in .NET

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid using `==` even when comparing String literals in Java, in case one of them _stops_ being a literal.

Answer (score 2):

```
field.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("formDateCreated")
```

Try this.
String trim() Method returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.

Comment: "formDateCreated".trim() no need to trim here since no spaces here

Comment: Yes,I know but may be user1582340 getting problem because of this.

Comment: No trim is note the issue. But you don't need to trim() this "formDateCreated"

Answer (score 1):

use `.equals()` method to check for **String equality** like `field1.equals("formDateCreated")`.
`==` operator just checks if two reference variables refer to the same string instance. `equals()` method checks if two strings are meaningfully equal.

Answer (score 1):

```
equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString)
```

for when you are not consider about case. This check weather your string content is equal not the reference which is ==

I would suggest you to check like bellow

```
"formDateCreated".equalsIgnoreCase(field)
```

So that it helps you to overcome possible NullPointerException